# git local branch overwrite files with another local branch

Tags: git

I have 3 branches `stage`, `mybranch` and `master`.

create `mybranch`

```
git pull origin master:mybranch
```

Now `stage` has about 80 commits i want to merge into `mybranch`

I've tried

```
git checkout mybranch
git merge stage
```

Also

```
git checkout mybranch
git pull origin stage
```

but they both don't merge all the commits. So how do i forcefully overwrite all files in `mybranch` with `stage` files?

Comment: That's unclear : at one point you say you want to merge `stage` into `yourbranch`, but later you refer to the operation as "forcefully overwrite". So which is it?

Comment: i want to overwrite, merge didn't work.

Comment: ...which `merge` is *not* meant to do. But ok, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve it, since you don't seem to need the history of your recently created local branch, is to point the ref directly where it should :

```
git branch -f mybranch stage
```

Although, do note that this will **not** merge `stage` into `mybranch`, but rather overwrite the latter with the former.